# Java do/while loop problem? How to count the string inside the loop

Tags: java

Here is the problem I was given: Write a program that takes website names as keyboard input until the user types the word 'stop' also count how many of the website names are commercial website names (i.e., end with .com), and output that count.

I can't figure out how to count the commercial website inside the loop and how to keep adding it if the user keeps adding more.

This is my code

```java
public class WebsiteNames {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //variables
        int commercialWebsite = 0;
        String commercialNames = "com";
        String website;
        final String SENTINEL = "stop";

        //scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a website url ");
        website = scan.next();

        //lenght of the website
        String substring = website.substring(website.length() - 3);

        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter a website url ");
            website = scan.next();
            substring = website.substring(website.length() - 3);

        } while (!SENTINEL.equals(website));
        System.out.println("There were " + commercialNames + " commercial websites entered");

    }
}
```

Comment: commercialWebsite++ inside the loop? Though I'm not sure why you're dropping the last three character without verifying their content, one can enter example.org

Comment: You're really close, you just need to increment your counter every time you hit a .com site.  I would use something like this inside your loop: `if (commercialNames.equals(substring)) { commercialWebsite++; }`  This will just add one to `commercialWebsite` if `substring` is "com".

Comment: You need to learn about using `if` . That simple. And note that the String class has methods such as `endsWith()` that you can use to say `if (someString.endsWith(".com"))` for example ...

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong thanks for the help! I forgot that I can use the if statement inside a loop

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for the reply! I forgot that I can use the If statement inside the loop. I've never learned the endWith() before thank you for teaching me!

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WebsiteNames {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // variables
        int commercialWebsite = 0;
        String commercialNames = ".com";
        String website;
        final String SENTINEL = "stop";

        // scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Please enter a website url (or 'stop' to terminate): ");
            website = scan.nextLine();
            if (website.endsWith(commercialNames)) {
                commercialWebsite++;
            }
        } while (!SENTINEL.equals(website));

        System.out.println("There were " + commercialWebsite + " commercial websites entered");
    }
}
```

- Use method [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) instead of method `next()`.
- Use method [endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) rather than method `substring()` since you are looking for Web sites whose names end with `.com`.
- You are using a `do-while` loop so no need to ask the user for input before entering the loop.
- Increment the counter, i.e. `commercialWebsite` if the entered Web site ends with the desired suffix.

Comment: There is still a difference between doing all the work, or simply enabling the OP to solve their problem themselves. Which of the two experiences will have a more motivating and lasting effect?

Answer (score 0):

i have done this with for loop.Its working as your requirements.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count=0;
    System.out.println("Enter website names:");
    String websites = scan.nextLine();
    String com = "com";
    String[] website = websites.split(" ");
   for (int i=0;i<website.length ;i++ ) 
    {
        if(website[i].substring(website[i].length()-3).equals(com)){
            count++;
        }  
        System.out.println("Names "+website[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("website Names="+websites);
    System.out.println("count "+count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this is to use `string.contains()`

Example for your application with some changes by my side:

```
 String website;
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a website url ");
        website = scan.nextLine();
        if(website.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
            break; // Go out of the loop

        if(website.contains(".com"))// if it contains the .com we increment the counter
            commercialWebsites++;

    }

    System.out.println("There were " + commercialWebsites + " commercial websites entered" );
```

Comment: No ti will not, but you can add this : `if(website.contains(".com") || website.contains(".org") )` then `commercialWebsites++`
This enables counting .org too

Comment: You've got different websites that end with .com.org or .com.de. It depends on the OP if he wants to count them or not. But the code is clear, **Contains** method clearly return true if the URL contains .com or .org and false else.
And our discussion here is just a question of whether he wants to count them or not.

Comment: @Abra to my knowledge i improved it by including even more commercial websites, if you think different, then be my guest. But it's not you whom I'm trying to help. It's the OP.

Comment: Why use contains for the ENDING of a string "a.commercial.tv" would be .com in your case ;-)

Comment: @Renis1235 so what if I do need to count .org or more website like .ca, .edu, .gov. How do I do that?

Comment: @SerAbs the easiest way is to add all the checks at the **if** like this: `if(website.contains(".com") || website.contains(".org") ) || website.contains(".ca")` etc
This operator || is the OR operator, so if the string contains .com OR .org OR .ca then increment my variable (commercialWebsites) 
Or you could follow the advice of @GhostCat here and use endsWith() instead of contains()

Comment: @Renis1235 when I do use the endsWith for some reason it counts everything that I enter even if its not .com as a commercial  website

Comment: @Renis1235 nvm i figured it out! I don't know how thought but I did lol